# Is there a ML Algorithm to map labels (Single or max a couple of words) to description (a text telling more about a label)

Tags: python, text-classification

So, I have a metadata dataset with labels and their descriptions.
A sample from the dataset looks like the following:

| **Label** | **Descriptions** |
| --- | --- |
| Release Date | Date of formal issuance |
| Language | The language of the dataset |

I want to train a ML model which learns the relationship between Label (Input X) and Descriptions (Target Y-categories) and then, can predict the category or the description of an unseen Label from the given list of Categories / Descriptions. Here we assume, the new label would be similar, in spelling or in meaning, to one of the labels used in the training model.

Unfortunately, most of the algorithms try to map the description (which is usually a text document, review etc) to one of the categories (positive or negative etc)

Would be great to get some help here, as to which algorithm would help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Non-programming questions (especially design questions) are better asked on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. It's not totally clear what the input is in this case. Assuming the input is made of a set of labels and a set of descriptions, this could be a matching problem. Technically it could be done using a similarity measure between the descriptions and labels, then picking the most similar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible: it can't be framed as a classification task nor a translation/transformation one, in fact at a high level the description is a better explaination of the label, tailored with external (domain?) knowledge that cannot be expressed in any model I know of.

Besides that, I don't think you have the necessary data amount and variability to express a sufficent generalization over the output.

Comment: Exactly, they won't be enough anyway for training the model, I think.

Comment: So, how about I generate synthetic data and then increase the size of my Dataset?

Comment: And also, I have tried reducing the descriptions to just stemmed words, removing all stopped words etc.

Comment: It then becomes a Natural Language Processing task, similar to text generation. You might want to look into NLP algorithms more in details, but still, you will need much more than 10s or 100s of pairs (label, description) for it to be of any interest.